# c++ primer 5th 1.4.4 why can't std::cout type out things immediately

Tags: c++

The 《c++ primer 5th》1.4.4 code example is like this

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;
    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1;  // store the count for the current value we're processing
        while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
            if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
                ++cnt;            // add 1 to cnt
            else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                          << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val;    // remember the new value
                cnt = 1;          // reset the counter
            }
        }  // while loop ends here
        // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
        std::cout << currVal <<  " occurs "
                  << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } // outermost if statement ends here
    return 0;
}
```

if i input :

11

11

13

13

13

14

I think it should execute like this :

when i input

11
11

the console should show "11 occurs 2 times".

Then i can continue to input

13
13
13

then the console should show " 13 occurs 3 times".

But the result is only when i have finished typing all the number , the console output the result once . why ?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: That is not what I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P1NxO.jpg

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're entering the values each on one line. The OP is entering all the numbers on a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Input from terminal is line buffered.

The first `std::cin >> currVal` blocks until input is available at standard input.

That doesn't happen until you press `<Enter>`. (Up to that `<Enter>`, the characters you entered are still residing in the line buffer of your terminal / CMD box. You can backspace, edit etc.; only when you press `<Enter>` does the terminal / CMD box actually send those characters to the program's standard input.)

For your expected behaviour to happen, try pressing `<Enter>` after each number.

Comment: As per his logic atleast the last input ( the one at which mis-match occur) be showing above the desired output line, As it is showing for @NathanOliver?

Comment: @DevanshMohanKaushik: Sorry but I do not understand what you are asking. The OP said he gave the input in one line, typing `11 11 13 13 13 14<Enter>`. The input "shows" because the terminal is displaying it; this has nothing to do with the program, which is still waiting for the input to appear, which it does the moment the OP presses `<Enter>`. *Then* the `if` and `while` execute, consume the input, produce the output (which appears under whatever the terminal produced during input), and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Both `std::cin >> currVal` in your sample will block the standard input, `std::cin` means a value that comes from standard input, in that case your keyboard is your standard input.

To confirm the input from keyboard you need to push `Enter` key, then values are removed from the `buffer` of the keyboard and processed by your code.

If you want to get the values for each press of key you need to use something like `std::getchar`, that function reads the buffer immediately like you expect.